# what prevents someone from exploiting route guarding vue js application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So I'm building my application to be protected by the `vue-router` library, but with simple getting started logic to protect the route, what actually prevents someone from making a fake "jwt" local storage key,value?

Sample:

```
function route_guard(to, from, next)
{
var isAuthenticated = false;
if(localStorage.getItem('jwt'))
  isAuthenticated = true;
 else
  isAuthenticated = false;
 if(isAuthenticated) 
 {
  next();
 } 
 else
 {
  next('/login');
 }
}
```

So when I add a fake "jwt" under localstorage, I am shown the application. What are some practices to properly authenticate with the route guard which would not allow this type of exploit, or if there is a better way please share.

Comment: Not a Vue user. As a general principle: each server-side view that handles private information needs to actually check the token is valid and the user is authorized to see the data requested. That is, the client-side check is just to send unauthenticated users to a login page instead of doing a request that will fail on the server anyway. (The client might also send the user to the login page if, say, they receive a 403 Forbidden or some more specific "you are not logged in" response.)

Comment: @twotwotwo so would there be some middle-ware for each page then as well? I'm new to vue, im actually more knowledgeable on the api and data side, and I have the routes set up to return a 401 if the user/pass fail, but to get to the actual application page would it make sense to not show the page unless you first check the jwt token?

Comment: I think the right way to look at this, no matter the client framework, is that code and data on the client are not secure.  Any real defend needs to take place at the server.

Comment: there should be a backend authentication check